# Is Symbol::gensym still useful any more after perl 5.6?

Tags: perl

I saw such code:

```
my $fh = gensym;                                             
open $fh, ">$name" or die "Can't create $name: $!";
```

which can be written as :

```
open my $fh, ">$name" or die "Can't create $name: $!";
```

Is `gensym` just legacy or still useful in some occasions?

Answer (score 8):

Legacy. Globs rather than lexicals sometimes required by older modules, but that's it.

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );
open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
my $pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD_STDIN',
   my $CHILD_STDOUT = gensym(),
   my $CHILD_STDERR = gensym(),
   $cmd, @args,
);
```

On second thought, you can also use them to create aliases (though [Data::Alias](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aAlias) can do this with lexicals).

```
my $foo;
our $bar; local *bar = \$foo;
$foo = 123; say $bar;  # 123
$bar = 456; say $foo;  # 456
```

Comment: Do you mean it won't work if I just pass `my $CHILD_STDOUT` directly in this case?

Comment: @new_perl, For stdout, that will work, but not for stderr. But also note that a glob is used for stdin. (Talking about `gensym` is silly since it's just `\local *NAME`, but with a new name every time.)

Comment: If you pass `undef` for the first and/or second argument, `open3` will call `gensym` for you. (That means that my $CHILD_STDOUT,` is actually `my $CHILD_STDOUT = gensym(),`) If you pass undef for the third argument, `open3` will use the same handle as the second argument. In other words, `undef` for the third argument is like the shell's `2>&1`.

Comment: Why must `open3` take a ref to glob as parameter, instead of a ref to simple scalar?

Comment: Why would it take a ref to a scalar??

Comment: Or maybe better rephrase the question as: why only glob can be used as file handle instead of scalar?

Comment: @new_perl, huh? globs are scalars.